# JavaScript input alerts user

Tags: javascript, html, css, file, input

I have the code below and what it currently does is if the user types index.html it will bring the to index.html etc. But what I want is if they type in a file that doesn't exist it alerts them. For example, they type hi.html and hi.html doesn't exist, it will then alert them saying the file doesn't exist.

The code:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.ex');
let inputPath = document.querySelector('.path');

// redirect to chosen path
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  location.href = inputPath.value;
});
```

```html
<input type='text' class='path' style="color: #222; background: white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 6px; border: none;">
<br><br><input type="submit" class="ex" value="Enter/submit" style="border-radius: 6px; font-size: 18px;display: inline-block; padding: 20px; border: none; background-color: royalblue; color: white;" />
```

Comment: If the user chooses a file then you know it exists

Comment: No I dont because what happens if the file doesn't exist it goes to a 404 page not found. I want it to alert the user instead

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to check against your available files to see if it's there. For example,

```js
let files = ['index.html', 'hello.html']
```

Then, in your event listener, you only allow valid files to reassign `location.href`. For the rest, you could send an alert. For example,

```js
if (files.some((file) => file == inputPath.value)) {
  location.href = inputPath.value
} else {
  alert('Not a valid path.')
}
```